# How to convert assignment operator string to actual assignment operation

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing all my conditions in a notepad for now so that I can access that file and use anytime for any change in condition for my dataframe.
My notepad txt file looks like below:

```
cond1 = (df['A'] == 1)
cond2 = (df['B'] >= 50)
```

When I read the text file, I get something like below:

```
["cond1 = (df['A] == 1)", "cond2 = (df['B] >= 50)"]
```

I wanted to convert this list to actual assignment operation. Like after execution, cond1 variable should be created and also cond2 as well. In case there are better way than storing in txt file, please advice as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create 4 columns in csv:

```
col,op,val,new
A,==,1,cond1
B,>=,50,cond2
```

Then create DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Last use operators for new columns:

```
import operator

ops = {'>': operator.gt,
       '<': operator.lt,
       '>=': operator.ge,
       '<=': operator.le,
       '==': operator.eq,
       '!=': operator.ne}

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,200,1], 'B':[200,1,10]})

for c,op,y,n in zip(df['col'], df['op'], df['val'], df['new']):
    df1[n] = ops[op](df1[c], y) 

print (df1)
     A    B  cond1  cond2
0   10  200  False   True
1  200    1  False  False
2    1   10   True  False
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use `eval()` or `exec()` functions. Check out this article [https://medium.com/@codingpilot25/difference-between-eval-and-exec-in-python-b387b25207d2#:~:text=Eval()%20only%20evaluates%20the,()%20it%20will%20throw%20error](https://medium.com/@codingpilot25/difference-between-eval-and-exec-in-python-b387b25207d2#:%7E:text=Eval()%20only%20evaluates%20the,()%20it%20will%20throw%20error).

1. `exec()` can be used to assign a value to variable, but `eval()` will throw error.
2. `eval()` only evaluates the single expression, not the complex logic code, whereas `exec()` can be used to execute any number of expression.
3. `exec()` accept the source code which contains statements like, for, while, print, import, class, if we pass these statement to `eval()` it will throw error.
4. `eval()` function evaluates the python code and returns the value, but `exec()` execute the code and always returns None,